# Changing a text in a span with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, prestashop-1.7

I have a PrestaShop 1.7 project with products sold by centimeters, so far no problem.

On the product sheet we have to display the remaining stocks, which are in a span, I want to change the term "999 Products" in "999 Centimeters" but only on some products by using the body class which indicates the ID number of the product.

If I do :

```
document.getElementById("nom_produit").innerHTML="Centimètres";
```

It works, of course, but on all products. I would like to do it only for some products.

Maybe using the Body class that indicates the product ID number:

```
body.product-id-12
```

Or another solution?

Comment: you must add a custom class for these products.

Answer (score 0):

either mark products with a class, if the backend supports it or go by id.

Create an array of ID's and loop thou them.